# Chrome extension - restart / re-enabled crashed extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have developped a Chrome Extensions that scrapes a couple of sites and every once in a while, it crashed. I'm still digging into it but I would like develop another extension that checks if the scraping extension still works and if not, restart it.

To achieve this, I have done the following:

1. I created an alarm that runs every minute

   ```
   var alarmName = 'Restarter';
   chrome.alarms.get(alarmName, function(Alarm) 
   {
   if (typeof Alarm === 'undefined')
       {
           console.log('is not defined');
           chrome.alarms.create(alarmName, 
               {
               periodInMinutes: 1
           });         
       }       
   else 
       {
           console.log('is defined');

       }       
   });
   ```
2. I created a listener to trigger the alarm

   chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(async function( alarm ) 
   {

   ```
   // first get your target (child) extension by it's name
   var child = null;
   found = 0;
   chrome.management.getAll(function (info) 
       {
           for (var i=0; i < info.length; i++) 
               {
                   console.log(info[i].name);
                   if ((info[i].name == 'Scraper v10bg'))
                       {
                           found = 1;
                           break;
                       }
               }
       });

   if (found == 0)
       {
           console.log('not found');
           enabled=1;
           chrome.management.setEnabled ("jalmlhajpmhnfajphkjlfedjdokhaabg", enabled, function () 
               { 
                   console.log('restarted');
               });

       }
   else
       {
           console.log('found');
       }
   });
   ```

This code does the following:
- it checks all enabled extension
- if it doesn't find the extension that I want (Scraper v10bg) it tries to restart it

When this code runs, I get the following error message:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Error in invocation of management.setEnabled(string id, boolean enabled, optional function callback): No matching signature.

I'm 100% sure the id is correct but I don't know what the signature issue means.

Do you have any idea of how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: You are trying to enable an extension that is not installed...

Comment: @IvánNokonoko The extension is installed and enabled.

Comment: Signature means the types of the parameters. Replace `enabled=1` with `enabled=true`.

Comment: @wOxxOm you're the best, that's exactly it ! If you want to add it as an answer, I'll mark it as resolved.